# Tailable cursor in Mongodb cluster

Tags: mongodb

A tailable cursor performs a collection scan over a capped collection. I have 3 replicaset 1 primary and 2 secondary which are in three different availability zone. In case of primary failure one of secondary will be elected as primary.

How does tailable cursor works in mongo cluster? If primary failed one of secondary will become primary. Once actual primary is recovered does tailable cursor also connect to it ?